# How to activate a debugger or access logs in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a R notebook on Microsoft's Azure notebooks cloud service.

When I am trying to run all cells, it displays a `Loading required package: ggplot2` in the last cell and then the Kernel systematically crashes. I get:

```
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

But the Kernel does not restart automatically.

How can I get a log describing the encountered issue? Is there a way to activate a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

When you're running Jupyter usually you'll see messages about kernel issues in standard I/O of the console that you launch.  In Azure Notebooks this gets redirected to a file at ~/.nb.log.  You can open a new terminal by clicking on the Jupyter icon, and then doing New->Terminal, and doing cat ~/.nb.log.  You could also start a new Python notebook for this purpose and do "!cat ~/.nb.log" - but unfortunately you can't just do that from an R notebook, they don't support the "magic" ! commands.

Usually that gives you a good starting point.  If that doesn't help much you could try invoking R directly from the terminal and trying the repro steps there and see if that's more useful.